# How to invalidate cache initialData in react query/tanstack query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query, tanstack, tanstackreact-query

I am using `useQuery` hook in TanStack Query *(previously React Query)* to cache data, in my case I config `initialData` depend on another hook `useInfiniteQuery` but when I am trying to invalidate `useInfiniteQuery`, cache from `useQuery` always immutate. In the following code below, the reason I do this way is because of my own intentions. Is there a way to force `initialData` to receive new data that depends on `item` ?

Post list component:

```
const queryClient = useQueryClient();
const { data } = useInfiniteQuery({ queryKey: ['posts'], ... });

const flatten = useMemo(() => data && data.pages.map((page) => page).flat(), [data]);

return (
   <>
     {flatten.map(post => (
        <Post key={post.id} item={post} />
     ))}

     // invalite cache from useInfiniteQuery to receive new cache
     <button onClick={() => queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['posts'] })}>
        Invalidate post
     </button>
   </>
)
```

Post component:

```
function Post ({ item }) {
  const { data } = useQuery({ 
    queryKey: ['post', item.id], 
    queryFn: getPost,
    enabled: !!item.id,
    initialData: item
  });

  // always get old cache data although value of item is mutated

  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data)}</pre>;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

query invalidation will re-run the QueryFunction, it has no effect on `initialData`. `initialData` is only used to fill the cache "initially" (once) if it has no data yet.

if you want to synchronously update the Query, use `queryClient.setQueryData`